# saml2.0 Generating metadata with OpenSAML

Tags: saml, opensaml

I am now trying to implement the Generating metadata with OpenSAML. For my reference I am using the http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.com/2012_02_01_archive.html blog to implement these scenario.I am new to saml.

In this implementation there is SAMLUtil class that has used to create the EntityDescriptor as EntityDescriptor spEntityDescriptor = SAMLUtil.buildSAMLObjectWithDefaultName(EntityDescriptor.class); .So I have added a dependency for org.apache.ws.security to import a class SAMLUtil.But I cannot find the method buildSAMLObjectWithDefaultName() for the specified class.

Can anyone help me to implement this scenario and tell me the way I have approached is exactly correct?

Answer (score 0):

The methods of SAMLUtil is published and explained [here](http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.no/2011/04/convenience-methods-for-opensaml.html)